# Smallest 2 Pin AC outlet socket

Tags: ac, diy, socket, outlet

For a home automation project I need to source panel mounting electrical outlet sockets which are as low profile as possible and are rated at least 200 watts.

Something like a female version of these figure of 8 connectors would be perfect but they don't appear to exist:

[image: figure of 8 socket]

EDIT: RE off topic. I'm not asking for shopping links, I'm trying to solve a design problem. I'll ask elsewhere, thanks to those who contributed.

Comment: hve seen plugs for those Moulded into the cases of plugs etc, but never as a distinct part

Comment: low profile in which dimension?  the standard US socket can be completely flat, just a couple of slots in a plate.  Do you have to meet any safety regulations?

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic in this forum and will be closed.  Reference: Help->Tour->Don't ask about...Shopping or buying recommendations.

Comment: This is a question about a type of plug, not necessarily a specific brand or manufacturer's product or a place to buy it. The question may not be considered off-topic. However it may turn out that there is only one manufacturer that meets the requirements.

Comment: @markrages low profile in depth especially, but also as small footprint a possible. no safety regs required, except basic sanity

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320 : the mating part is an IEC C7, but doesn't seem to exist in panel mount. The larger ones do.

Comment: An "outlet" version of this connector theoretically exists (look at the "interconnection coupleers" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320 . I don't think i've ever seen one for sale as  seperate item though.

Comment: I actually just found a female IEC_60320 C7 outlet however it mounts using large wings on each end which are screwed on to the panel rather than clicked in. Still, its the closest thing I can find..

Answer (score 1):

Plugs and sockets are not rated in watts. You need to look for specific voltage and current ratings such as 120V, 2A or 240V, 1A. For the one that you found, find the name and/or number for that type of plug and search for that. Also use other terms for the type of mounting such as chassis mount or thru-hole mount.

Another alternative to the type of plug that you found is a Cinch, Jones, or Cinch-Jones plug. They are rated 250V, 10A and are very compact. There is a 2-pin plug of that type, but there may not be a thru-hole receptacle (socket or female plug). The 4-pin receptacle is available as a thru-hole mount and may be smaller than anything else you can find even though you would have two wasted pins.

Comment: I had a look at the Cinch Jones connectors and even the 2-pin variant is over an inch square.

Answer (score 0):

2-pin Amp (Tyco Electronics) "Mate'n'Loc" connectors are similar in size to the connector that you show and both sexes (Male & Female) are available as chassis-mount.  They have plastic tabs that lock into the sides of the rectangular opening that the connector is mounted into.

The only downside is that you need a proper crimp tool to attach the pins to the conductors for reliable connection.  These tools range in price from under $100 to several hundred dollars, depending on model.

This family of connectors is **extremely** reliable - we have been using them for decades, built into equipment that has to last for decades.

Comment: These look good, my only concern is they sit proud of the panel (aesthetic concern) and I can't tell if they would allow small finger access to the pins on the panel connector. I need a connector which is safe when not being utilized.